# Cross-Origin Request Blocked with POST But working fine with req on Browser but on device not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an application using ionic. I am using this code

```
  var req = 
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: API_END_POINT + "/accounts/login",
                        data: this.toparams(myobject),
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    }

                    $http(req).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                    {
                       if(data.result = 'success') {
                console.log('Success', data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(0);
            }
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                    {
                        console.error('ERR');
     deferred.resolve(0);
                    });

            return deferred.promise;
```

}

This is working fine on browsers but not on device ..

Even if i tired using this method

var link = API_END_POINT +"/accounts/login";

```
$http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username,password:$scope.data.password}).then(function (res){
    $scope.response = res;
});
```

This gives me CORS error on browser.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: When you are testing in browser, are both your ajax calling page and api endpoint have the same domain, e.g http://localhost:8080?

Comment: no. i am using server endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check your server, because default configuration of most used servers forbids Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

You can read this website to configure your server:

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: if this is CORS issue , then why  i am able to respond using 

http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username,password:$scope.data.password}).then(function (res){
    $scope.response = res;
});

Comment: Does `$scope.data.username,password:$scope.data.password}) ...` work in your device?

Comment: I took this info from WIkipedia: .. AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) requests have traditionally been limited to accessing the same domain as the parent web page (as per the same-origin security policy). "Cross-domain" AJAX requests are forbidden by default because of their ability to perform advanced requests (POST, PUT, DELETE and other types of HTTP requests, along with specifying custom HTTP headers) that introduce many cross-site scripting security issues. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing]

Comment: If you want to make a request from a different "place" that you API domain you have to change you server configuration

Comment: so you mean i have to make chnages on server side ?

Comment: Yes. For example, if you use Apache Tomcat as server you should edit your sever.xml like this:  http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html